# Java API to access a dongle?

Tags: java, mysql, dongle

I'm planning to implement a desktop application which stores all the SMSs and senders' numbers received to the dongle in a MySQL database. So, is there any method I can use to access the dongle in order to reach the above mentioned targeted function?

Comment: Storing the message content and sender's number in to a mysql database.

Comment: If you have the connection to the DB on the dongle, there's nothing special you need to do.

Comment: If I have, then no problem at all...Am searching for it anyway.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dongle allocates some serial port you should be able to access this and use AT commands.

Look at the "Java communications API", a code sample here:

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=22

Comment: Are there any java APIs that I can use for this?